# Probability when splitting a poisson process

Tags: split, process, probability, poisson, rate

I'm splitting a poisson process where the mean arrival rate is lambda (20) and it splits into two independent processes with probability p and (1-p).
I'm also given that the processing rates of the two independent processes are mu(1) = 10 and mu(2) = 15

Can anyone help direct me to the derivation of p so both independent processes have the same utilisation? Thanks

Comment: Your question doesn't involve programming or software, so you'd probably do better over on stats.stackexhcange.com.

Comment: Not sure what you want?  The total processing rate is 25.  Therefore the first wants 10/25 of the traffic and the second wants 15/25 of the traffic.  That's a p of 0.4.  And then double check, both wind up with 80% utilization.